# Omniauth + Devise - multiple models with multiple providers (warden problems and states)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

this question is a bit different than asking about setting devise :omniauthable with multiple providers (facebook, etc.). The situation is more complex.

FYI - I'm using Rails 3.2.16

I have two kinds of users - Secure (who use phone number + SMS verification code to login the first time) and Insecure (who can either use a provider or a simple email/password to login the first time). After the first login, both kinds of users are forced to choose an email and password (just in case their facebook account is deleted or something). Both these users can go into their account and choose to "associate" more providers with their account. Subsequently, both these users can login through whatever they choose - with Secure users having the additional phone number login.

Now, associating multiple providers with a user is something I understand - you create the Identities model and associate it with the User using Omniauth Callbacks. What I dont understand is the following:

1. I want to keep using Devise (if possible) for the email/password authentication. It gives me nice things like "stretches", etc. After a successful sign_in through Facebook (which is Omniauth), how do I force creation of an email/password with an email confirmation step (which is Devise). The user should not be able to proceed further, until this is done. This is an interplay of Devise and Omniauth that I dont understand. I do know that Devise and Omniauth can co-exist because they live on separate routes fundamentally.
2. Even more tricky - the way we have two completely different ways of first time authentication (e.g. the SMS code) is to have different models. Rolify and Cancan are not very helpful here. However, this means that on successful authentication, there are two separate warden session variables "warden.user.secureuser" and "warden.user.insecureuser". This is causing the app to have someone logged-in as two separate **types** of users **simultaneously**. How do I prevent this ?  I know that this isnt really wrong, but I would prefer not to have that.
   FYI - I dont have any common routes between the two types of users. for example everything for insecureuser lives in "/insecureuser/*" and vice versa at "/secureuser/*".

Comment: I have looked at https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/domp.git and https://github.com/jsmestad/socialite/blob/master/lib/socialite/models/user_concern.rb to understand how to build find_from_omniauth,etc. functions - but I still cant pull the above off.